# How to calculate the length of a cycle $(i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k)\in S_n$ in GAP(Groups, Algorithms, Programming)?

Tags: math-software, gap

I am new to GAP ( - Groups, Algorithms, Programming - a System for Computational Discrete Algebra).
I want to calculate the length of a cycle $(i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k)\in S_n$. (I want to get $k$ from $(i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k)\in S_n$.)
Please tell me how to calculate the length of a cycle $(i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k)\in S_n$ in GAP?

```
Length(1,2,3);
```

didn't work.

```
Order(1,2,3);
```

worked.

But is this a right way to calculate the length of a cycle in GAP?

Comment: Rob Pratt, Thank you for your edit.

Comment: Alexander Konovalov, Thank you for your edit.

Comment: You're welcome! Also use backticks for short code fragments and three backticks fo longer blocks of code instead of indenting by 4 spaces (see how I use them in my answer). This makes it easy to copy and paste code and fragments of GAP sessions to/from this site.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Thank you very much for teaching me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a cycle, then I think that using `Order` will be the best way. It will use fast implementation from the GAP kernel - as you can see, repeating this calculation a million times takes a bit more than a second:

```
gap> for i in [1..1000000] do Order((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));od;time;
1238
```

If you have a product of several cycles, then `CycleStructurePerm` would be a proper way to get the number of cycles of each length. It's also fast:

```
gap> for i in [1..1000000] do CycleStructurePerm((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10));od;time;
1400
```

P.S. Of course, one should be careful when dealing with the identity permutation:

```
gap> Order(());
1
gap> NrMovedPoints(());
0
gap> CycleStructurePerm(());
[  ]
```

These functions are documented in [this manual chapter](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap42.html).

Comment: Alexander Konovalov, Thank you very much for your kind answer.